# How to write "AND" and "OR" in WHERE clause in a Medoo SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, medoo

I'm trying to write a complex SQL select statement in Medoo that involves some AND criteria and some OR criteria.

The following is the statement I wrote:

```
debug()->select("ValuesEvaluationInstrument", "*", ["AND"=> ['secondReviewComplete' => "Yes"], "OR" => $filters]);
```

This prints the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM "ValuesEvaluationInstrument" WHERE "yearInstrumentPublished" IN ('2019','2018','2017','2016','2015','2014','2013','2012','2011','2010') OR "validated" IN ('Yes') OR "secondReviewComplete" IN ('Yes')
```

However, it should print:

```
SELECT * FROM "ValuesEvaluationInstrument" WHERE "yearInstrumentPublished" IN ('2019','2018','2017','2016','2015','2014','2013','2012','2011','2010') OR "validated" IN ('Yes') AND "secondReviewComplete" IN ('Yes')
```

What I'm trying to achieve is get the "secondReviewComplete" column to be an AND so that all results returned have this column as Yes.

Can someone please help writing this correctly?

Comment: Probably will need to know what the contents of `$filters` is

Comment: You can see the contents in the sql query that's being printed out.

Answer (score 1):

I have just figured it out. Posting this here for anyone else who may have the same problem:

```
debug()->select("ValuesEvaluationInstrument", "*", ["AND"=> ['secondReviewComplete' => "Yes", "OR" => $filters] ]);
```

Upvote if this helps.